# Visual Composer Accordion (WordPress) doesnt work properly

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

the accordion **on mobile screen** doesnt work as it should.

1. Sometimes the tabs cannot be opened.
2. You cant close opened tabs.
3. If you open another tab it does not jump to the beginning of the new opened tab.

this is the WordPress-Site: http://neuronade.com

This is the code behind (I guess):

**vc_accordions.php**

```html
<?php
$title = $interval = $el_class = $output = '';

extract( shortcode_atts( array(
 'title'     => '',
 'heading_title'   => '',
 'interval'     => 0,
 'style'     => 'fancy-style',
 'container_bg_color'  => '#fff',
 'el_position'    => '',
 'open_toggle'    => 0,
 'responsive'    => 'true',
 'action_style'    => 'accordion-style',
 'el_class'     => ''
), $atts ) );


$id = uniqid();

// The logic is inverted in options to whatever we have in code so tweak it as this
// to get to right output without breaking potentially right code.
// Current state output classes that mean:
// mobile-true - the shortcode is disabled for mobile and all panes are expanded
// mobile-false - the shortcode is enabled, panesare toggled and clickable to change its state
$responsive = ($responsive == 'true') ? 'false' : 'true';

if ( !empty( $heading_title ) ) {
 $output .= '<h3 class="mk-shortcode mk-fancy-title pattern-style mk-shortcode-heading"><span>'.$heading_title.'</span></h3>';
}
$output .= '<div data-style="'.$action_style.'" data-initialIndex="'.$open_toggle.'" id="mk-accordion-'.$id.'" class="mk-accordion mk-shortcode mobile-'.$responsive.' '.$style.' '.$el_class.'">';
$output .= wpb_js_remove_wpautop($content);
$output .= '</div>';


// Get global JSON contructor object for styles and create local variable
global $app_dynamic_styles;
$container_bg_color = !empty($container_bg_color) ? ('background-color:'.$container_bg_color.';') : '';
$app_styles = '
 #mk-accordion-'.$id.' .mk-accordion-pane{
    '.$container_bg_color.'
}';


echo $output;


// Hidden styles node for head injection after page load through ajax
echo '<div id="ajax-'.$id.'" class="mk-dynamic-styles">';
echo '<!-- ' . mk_clean_dynamic_styles($app_styles) . '-->';
echo '</div>';


// Export styles to json for faster page load
$app_dynamic_styles[] = array(
  'id' => 'ajax-'.$id ,
  'inject' => $app_styles
);
```

**vc_accordion_tab.php**

```html
<?php
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
 'title' => __( "Section", "mk_framework" ),
 'icon'  => '',
), $atts ) );

$output = '';
if(!empty( $icon )) {
    $icon = (strpos($icon, 'mk-') !== FALSE) ? ( '<i class="'.$icon.'"></i>' ) : ( '<i class="mk-'.$icon.'"></i>' );    
} else {
 $icon = '';
}
$output .= "\n\t\t\t\t" . '<div class="mk-accordion-single"><div class="mk-accordion-tab">'.$icon.'<span>'.$title.'</span></div>';
$output .= "\n\t\t\t\t" . '<div class="mk-accordion-pane">';
$output .= ($content=='' || $content==' ') ? __("Empty section. Edit page to add content here.", 'mk_framework') : "\n\t\t\t\t" . wpb_js_remove_wpautop($content, true);
$output .= "\n\t\t\t\t" . '<div class="clearboth"></div></div></div>';

echo $output;
```

Comment: i thing your js conflict problem .

Comment: sort it out the js problem, see the console

Comment: Sorry I am no Code-Expert, just editing some CSS mostly.
What exactly do you mean?

Comment: You should check dev tools by hitting F12 and check the console tab for any Java script errors.